# printing a pdf with python from a specific path

Tags: python, macos, unix

I was trying to make a simple program that could print a pdf file I have in a folder. (I'm currently running a Mac OS)

I used the command lpr -P from os but I could make it work only if the file is in the same folder as the python file.

This is the code I wrote to print a pdf file named "1.pdf"

```
import os

var = 1
path = "lpr -P HP_LaserJetPro_M118-M119 /output_pics/pdf/" + str(var) + ".pdf"
os.system(path)
```

but I got the "No such file or directory" error, what did I wrong? (the folder output_pics is in the same directory of the py file)

Answer (score 0):

/path/to/file refers to an absolute path, starting from the root directory. If you want a relative directory, as in your case, change

```
/output_pics/pdf/
```

to

```
./output_pics/pdf/
```

The . here refers to your current directory.

Comment: I tried but I got the error "lpr: the printer or the class doesn't exist"

Comment: That's a different problem entirely. And one I don't think I can help you debug - it sounds like lpr doesn't see your printer.

Comment: I copied the name that appear on my computer changing spaces with "_". Is there any way to see a list of printers installed on the system which the lp command could recognize?